# How to do enums in kie workbecnh/Drools 6.2

Tags: java, drools, kie, kie-workbench

I might be on the wrong track here so please correct me if so.

I have a data model with a member called `action` which is an **enum**. So looks like this:

**Contract class:**

```
public class Contract {

    public Action action;

    public Action getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(Action action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

**Action class:**

```
public enum Action {

    CREATE, AMEND, RENEWAL

}
```

Now, the problem is that I can not replicate this data model in Kie Workbench as it seems not to support enums? Or maybe I do not know how to implement them?

Which in turn means that when I fetch the rules via the Kie Execution Server, because I can not have an **action** member of type **Action** (which is an enum) the following rule will never get fired:

```
rule "Contract rule"
when
    $c : Contract ( action.equals("CREATE") ) 
then
    System.out.println("This order action is: " + $c.getAction());
end
```

Is there a workaround here? Am I missing something?

If you wanna see the error that I get when I implement the following code, here it is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.heg.projectdelta.contractcreator.model.Contract.getAction()Lcom/heg/projectdelta/contractcreator/model/Action;
    at com.heg.projectdelta.contractcreator.model.Rule_Contract_rule116883127.defaultConsequence(Rule_Contract_rule116883127.java:7)
    at com.heg.projectdelta.contractcreator.model.Rule_Contract_rule116883127DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at com.heg.projectdelta.contractcreator.model.Rule_Contract_rule116883127DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1114)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:160)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:108)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:1016)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1302)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1289)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1262)
    at com.heg.projectdelta.cedroolscore.service.DroolsService.fireAllRules(DroolsService.java:115)
    at com.heg.projectdelta.contractcreator.service.impl.DroolsWebServiceImpl.fireRules(DroolsWebServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.heg.projectdelta.contractcreator.integration.DroolsWebServiceTest.testFireRules(DroolsWebServiceTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the workbench would permit or refute the use of enum classes, but if you were to write the rule in plain DRL, it would have to be

```
rule "Contract rule"
when
    $c : Contract ( action == Action.CREATE ) 
then
    System.out.println("This order action is: " + $c.getAction());
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It actually fixed my problem.